# In poky-tiny, why adding openssh also adds bash?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

When I build the `core-image-minimal` of poky-tiny, `bash` is not included.
When I add the package `openssh-sshd` in IMAGE_INSTALL, then `bash` is added in the image. Why?

(`bash` is not needed in my case and is cumbersome)

I looked at the result of `bitbake -e` but did not find the reason.

What other means do I have other than looking at bitbake source code and putting some debug prints everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was wrong: `bash` is not included in the built image.

The files `recipe-depends.dot` and `pn-buildlist` (resulting from `bitbake -g`) indicate the presence of `bash`, but after actually building the image, `bash` is not in the manifest nor in the image.

I cannot explain this difference.

I am going to close or delete my question (because it is a wrong question).